# How can I load specific data from an excel database to python?

Tags: python, pandas, database, load, multiple-columns

I am trying to add 4 columns from a database in excel, 2 of those columns must be filtered and I am trying with "usecols" but it does not work, is there any other way to select specific data?

```
df = pd.read_excel('BD_completa.xlsx', sheet_name='Hoja1', usecols=['[Fecha Orden Compra]','precio_del_bien','[Código Artículo]'==32, '[Código Rubro]'==2])
```

and i have the next error:

> ValueError: 'usecols' must either be list-like of all strings, all unicode, all integers or a callable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  If your question concern a pandas dataframe, then learn how to make a  [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: What is `'[Código Artículo]'==32` meant to do? The issue is that your `usecols` list contains a mixture of strings and boolean values, which is invalid.